# Having two sets of bearing and elevation measurements, find the height of the balloon

Tags: trigonometry

This is problem `6.3.8` from *Trigonometry: A Complete Introduction*, by  Hugh Neill (ISBN 1473678498). It's in the surveying chapter, which is a practical continuation of the sine and cosine rules of the chapter before that. So I'm assuming you don't need much more than those two rules. It's a simple problem, but I'm a beginner in maths, so I'm struggling.

<sub>I've written a lot of Latex for such a small problem, but it's the first time I'm writing in it, and I find it fascinating. It looks so cool! So, if I appear too pedantic, it's because of my enthusiasm.</sub>

### The problem

> Two observers 5 kilometers apart measure the bearing of the base of the balloon and the angle of elevation of the balloon at the same instant. One finds that the bearing is 041°, and the elevation is 24°. The other observer finds that the bearing is 032°, and the elevation is 26.62°. Calculate the height of the balloon.

The book also gives this answer:

> 2.23 km

I cannot get to that answer. Any help would be appreciated.

---

### My attempt

The are two planes: the bearing plane (Fig. 1) and the elevation plane (Fig 2). Both planes have `AC` and `BC` in common. We then express them both in terms of `CD` (the height, `h`) by employing the sine rule, and carry them to the bearing plane. There, we apply the cosine rule, after which we end up with an equation, and then finally we solve for `h` (`CD`).

[image: Flat land - a confusing story]

[image: How high]

We first calculate the remaining angles of the two right triangles:
$$ \angle ADC = 90° - 24° = 66° \tag{1} $$
$$ \angle BDC = 90° - 26.62° = 63.38° \tag{2} $$
We then apply the sine rule, to express `AC` and `BC` in terms of the height `h` (`CD`). In $\triangle ACD$, we have:
$$ \frac{AC}{\sin{66°}} = \frac{h}{\sin{24°}} \Rightarrow AC = \frac{h\cdot\sin{66°}}{\sin{24°}} \tag{3} $$
In $\triangle BCD$, we have:
$$ \frac{BC}{\sin{63.38°}} = \frac{h}{\sin{26.62°}} \Rightarrow BC = \frac{h\cdot\sin{63.38°}}{\sin{26.62°}} \tag{4} $$

That's the bearing plane. Now onto the elevation plane. From Fig. 1, I calculated that
$$ \angle ACB = 9° \tag{5} $$

Applying the cosine rule in $\triangle ABC$, with respect to $\angle ACB$, we get:
$$ AB^2 = AC^2 + BC^2 - 2 \cdot AB \cdot BC \cdot \cos{\angle ACB} \tag{6} $$
We already know that `AB` is 5 km from the problem description, so, substituting values from `(3)`, `(4)` and `(5)`, we get:

$$ \left(h \cdot \frac{\sin{66°}}{\sin{24°}} \right)^2 + \left(h \cdot \frac{\sin{63.38°}}{\sin{26.62°}} \right)^2 - 2 \cdot \left(h \cdot \frac{\sin{66°}}{\sin{24°}} \right) \cdot \left(h \cdot \frac{\sin{63.38°}}{\sin{26.62°}}\right) \cdot \cos{9°} = 25 \tag{7} $$

$$ Let x = \frac{\sin{66°}}{\sin{24°}} and y = \frac{\sin{63.38°}}{\sin{26.62°}} \tag{8} $$
$$ (hx)^2 + (hy)^2 - 2(hx)(hy)\cos{9°} = 25 \tag{9} $$
$$ h^2x^2 + h^2y^2 - 2h^2xy\cos{9°} = 25 \tag{10} $$
$$ h^2 \cdot (x^2 + y^2 - 2xy\cos{9°}) = 25 \tag{11} $$
$$ h^2 =  \frac{25}{x^2 + y^2 - 2xy\cos{9°}} \tag{12} $$
$$ h = \frac{5}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 - 2xy\cos{9°}}} \tag{13} $$
We start using the calculator:
$$ x = \frac{\sin{66°}}{\sin{24°}} = 2.246036774 \tag{14} $$
$$ y = \frac{\sin{63.38°}}{\sin{26.62°}} = 1.995213989 \tag{15} $$
$$ \cos{9°} = 0.987688341 \tag{16} $$
Substituting `(14)`, `(15)` and `(16)` into `(13)` we get (quickly, let me use the awesome <s>"therefore"</s> "tombstone" sign!):
$$ h = 12.01225202 \blacksquare \tag{17} $$

---

### Using $\cot$

Using $\cot$, as `orangeskid` suggested, gets me:
$$ AC = h \cdot \cot 24° = h \cdot \frac{1}{\tan 24°} \tag{18} $$
$$ BC = h \cdot \cot 26.62° = h \cdot \frac{1}{\tan 26.62°} \tag{19} $$
Plugging these two into the cosine rule expressed in `(6)`, I get into a similar point as with using the sine rule ratios - `(3)` and `(4)` -, where I have to extract some variables. These are:
$$ x = \frac{1}{\tan{24°}} = 2.24603677 \tag{20} $$
$$ y = \frac{1}{\tan{26.62°}} = 1.99521398 \tag{21} $$
Which are the same values as `(14)` and `(15)`, and thus I get the same value as `(17)`.

This makes sense mathematically, since a cotangent can be expressed in terms of a ratio of sines of opposite acute angles (which was nice to infer, as I hadn't realised it):
$$ \frac{\sin\angle ADC}{\sin\angle DAC} = \frac{\sin(90° - \angle DAC)}{\sin\angle DAC} = \frac{\cos\angle DAC}{\sin\angle DAC} = \cot\angle DAC \implies eq(3) = eq(18) $$

---

That's not what the book says, however. See the spoiler from the beginning.

I'm not sure where I got it wrong. I suspect that maybe the $\angle ACB$ angle is wrong, because, if I reverse-engineer the problem, assuming the value is the one from the given book, I end up with its value being $≈63°$, which is quite different from my $9°$. But how can that angle be 63 degrees, I've no clue.

Where did I get it wrong?

Let me know your thoughts. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The book was wrong. I was right. The correct answer is $ \approx 12 km $. Beware, Riemann Hypothesis!

The confirmation came when I stumbled across an [OCR'd](https://archive.org/stream/teach-yourself-trigonometry/Teach%20Yourself%20Trigonometry_djvu.txt) version of what seems to be the original book that my workbook was inspired from: "Teach Yourself Trigonometry", by P. Abbott, the 1975 edition. Search for `Two observers` to get to the problem, and `11990` to get to the answer.

There's also a scanned version, too. Here's the actual page with the problem: [archive.org link](https://archive.org/details/teach-yourself-trigonometry/page/146/mode/2up). Notice problem 8, exercise (group) 26, on page 146.
*(Although it says $ 26° 37^\prime $, that computes to $ 26.61666° \approx 26.62° $, which is what my problem used in its statement. I guess they did away with the minutes lest it boggled our minds.)*

Now, may I direct your attention to the answer on page 203: [link](https://archive.org/details/teach-yourself-trigonometry/page/202/mode/2up). 11990 m!

Let me laugh in Latex: $ \blacksquare $

<sub>While I am getting 12.01 and not 11.99, I blame the 1975 calculators. I'm picking my battles here. Also, I need to get in touch with the author/publisher somehow.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
Finding $h$ is equivalent to finding $AC$, or $BC$.
The sides $AC$ and $BC$ are proportional to $\cot 24^{\circ}$, $\cot 26.62$. Also we know $AB$. That in itself is not enough to solve the triangle $ABC$. But, we have an extra information, the angle at $C$.  Now this should be a standard problem.  I advise to focus on $\Delta ABC$, and solve it using letter variables, then switch to numerics in the end, like you would do with a physics problem.

Comment: thanks for the hint. i attempted it, but unfortunately I got the same result. see `(18)` and `(19)`. your solution and mine are mathematically equivalent, I think. did I miss something from your suggestion?